How to import Different branches of same submodule in eclipse
I am working on 2 different Spring boot multi-module projects where both projects are pointing to different branches of a same submodule. So question is how to import both projects with different versions/ branches of same submodule?
Let say, I want to import 2 multi-modules projects p1 and p2. Both projects are pointing to submodule project m1. Project p1 will use m1(branch b1) and project p2 will use m1(branch b2). So how can I import both projects with different versions of same submodule in eclipse STS?
Note that code of m1(branch b1) is inside p1 while m1(branch b2) code is in p2 project directory
